# Multiprocessing library in python unable to import a custom defined module and also doesn't work when function defined in same python file

Tags: python, python-3.x, multiprocessing

I'm working on trying to check if a particular image has a duplicate by using multiprocessing. There is a function called `find_duplicate`  which takes an image as an argument and checks if the original image is same as the image given in the argument. So, I tried defining the function in the same python file and tried calling it using `multiprocessing.Process(find_duplicates, (image,))` where `image` is the argument that I pass to the function that I defined in the same page. But, I get the following error

```
AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'find_duplicates' on <module '__main__' (built-in)>
```

Next, I saw that I could put it in a separate python file and I wrote that function inside a python file called **multiple_core_function.py** and tried importing it in my python file using

```
import multiple_core_function as mcf
```

Then, I used the same code to call that function and instead of direcrtly typing `find_duplicates`, I typed `mcf.find_duplicates` and this time, I got the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\aniru\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 116, in spawn_main
    exitcode = _main(fd, parent_sentinel)
  File "C:\Users\aniru\anaconda3\lib\multiprocessing\spawn.py", line 126, in _main
    self = reduction.pickle.load(from_parent)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'multiple_core_function'
```

After this, I thought that the problem is because the **multiple_core_function.py** is not in the location given and then I copied the file and pasted it in the same level as spawn.py in multiprocessing. Unsurprisingly, it still didn't work.

My code for the main file is here

```
import cv2
import glob
import time
import multiprocessing
import multiple_core_function as mcf


"""
Multiprocessing
"""

if __name__ == '__main__':
    image_name = '..\\Images_test\\original_golden_bridge.jpg'
    original = cv2.imread(image_name) 
    mcf.set_original(image_name)
    
    def filebrowser(ext='', directory=''):
        """
        returns files with an extension
        """
        return [f for f in glob.glob(f"{directory}**/*{ext}", recursive=True)]

    image_dir = filebrowser(ext='.jpeg', directory='..\\Images_test') # directory='' ==> search images from current to inner sub-directories
    image_dir += filebrowser(ext='.jpg', directory='..\\Images_test')
    

    start_time = time.time()
    processes = []
    # pool = multiprocessing.Pool() 

    

    # inputs = image_dir
    # pool.map_async(find_duplicates, inputs)
    # # print(outputs_async.get())
    # pool.close()
    for image_ in image_dir:
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target = mcf.find_duplicates, args = (image_,))
        processes.append(process)
        process.start()
    
    for process in processes:
        process.join()

    print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
    print('Program Executed Completely')
```

And the code inside **multiple_core_function** is

```
import cv2

def set_original(name):
    global image_name
    image_name = name
    global original
    original = cv2.imread(image_name)

def find_duplicates(image_):
    print('Welcome')
    duplicates = ''
    try:
        image_to_compare = cv2.imread(image_)
        print('Image read!')
        if original.shape == image_to_compare.shape:

            difference = cv2.subtract(original, image_to_compare)
            b, g, r = cv2.split(difference)

            if cv2.countNonZero(b) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(g) == 0 and cv2.countNonZero(r) == 0:
                print(f'Duplicates Found: {image_name} is Duplicate of {image_}')
                duplicates = image_


                sift = cv2.xfeatures2d.SIFT_create()
                kp_1, desc_1 = sift.detectAndCompute(original, None)
                kp_2, desc_2 = sift.detectAndCompute(image_to_compare, None)

                index_params = dict(algorithm=0, trees=5)
                search_params = dict()
                flann = cv2.FlannBasedMatcher(index_params, search_params)

                matches = flann.knnMatch(desc_1, desc_2, k=2)

                good_points = []
                for m, n in matches:
                    if m.distance < 0.6*n.distance:
                        good_points.append(m)

                # Define how similar they are
                number_keypoints = 0
                if len(kp_1) <= len(kp_2):
                    number_keypoints = len(kp_1)
                else:
                    number_keypoints = len(kp_2)

                return duplicates

    except Exception as e:
        pass
```

The `set_original` was to set some variables to use inside the `find_duplicates` and I had also tried to use `multiprocessing.Pool` to try this, but got the same two sets of errors.

Can someone tell me how to correct this?

Comment: It's good that you show your effort to solve it yourself, but can you frame this as a question?

Comment: Really sorry about that, I changed it now.